# AJAX events logging in Google Chrome extension

Tags: ajax, events, event-handling, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on google chrome extension which logs multiple events. I have a problem with AJAX events. I found this code to log every single AJAX event:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event){
            console.log("AJAX event");
    });
```

But it logs hundreds of them. Does anybody know how to distinguish which page element fired which event? And what caused the event (click, mouse move)?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the event type by simply calling `event.type` in your callback function. You should get click/mousemove/mouseover etc. Try `console.log(event)` and see what else you can find too!

Comment: That's strange when I do the same thing (also in Chrome) I get the type of the event in `event.type`

Comment: "DOMSubtreeModified | [object HTMLDivElement] | undefined " for type|target|which properties. Only target changes sometimes but usually it's the same.